# Error with longfbox package

Tags: compilation-error

I defined a box to contain headers for each section in an instruction file. I have been using this personally defined box for quite a long time and it worked fine all the time. A MWE is as follows:

```
\ducumentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longfbox}

\newcommand*{\mylbox}[1]{\lfbox[border-style=double, border-width=3pt, width = \textwidth, 
padding=4pt]{\textbf{\centerline{\Large #1}}}}

\newcommand*{\mysbox}[1]{\centerline{\lfbox[border-radius = 1.5ex, border-width=2pt,
 padding=4pt, padding-left = 10em, padding-right = 10em]{\textbf{\large #1}}}}

\begin{document}
\mylbox{General Information}
\end{document}
```

However, when I made a few changes in the text (this can't be the reason), I got a lot of errors when I compile the file. Two examples of those error messages would be:

> quote ! Undefined control sequence.\fbox@border@hcornerarc@ ...er -x}\fi @tempdimd
> \fbox@adjusty {@tempdimb ...
> l.71 \mylbox{General Information}

> quote ! You can't use `\dimexpr' in restricted horizontal mode.\fbox@adjusty #1->\dimexpr
> \option {/fbox/@border-box-height} - #1\relax
> l.71 \mylbox{General Information}

A more complete list of error messages can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFsrv.jpg).

What is the problem? The only thing I did was that I updated many packages via MikTex like two days ago. Nothing else.

If you also need further details about a specific error, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, `longfbox` relies on a scratch register `\@tempdimd` that used to be allocated by `pict2e`, but no longer is.

You solve the issue by adding

```
\makeatletter
\newdimen\@tempdimd
\makeatother
```

in your document preamble. By the way, there is no need for `\centerline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longfbox}

\makeatletter
\newdimen\@tempdimd
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\mylbox}[1]{%
  \lfbox[
    border-style=double,
    border-width=3pt,
    width = \dimexpr\textwidth-14pt,
    padding=4pt,
  ]{\hfill\bfseries\Large #1\hfill}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\mylbox{General Information}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: thanks to campa who noted in comments that `\@tempdimd` used to exist in `pict2e`.

Comment: Uhm, `longfbox` loads `pict2e` which _does_ define `\@tempdimd`, so that cannot really be the issue, can it?

Comment: Oh, wait, I have version `0.3b`. In version `0.4b` that has been renamed to `\pIIe@tempdimd`. That might be worth adding to your answer.

Comment: @campa I'd not use the specific register of `pict2e` anyway. Better allocating a new one; the package maintainer can easily fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I noticed that you made a few changes in the definition of `mylbox`: for width, it was changed from `\textwidth` to `\dimexpr\textwidth - 14pt`. Why is the latter one better? Could you please also explain a bit about the changes made in curly brackets? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @LinJing With `\textwidth` you get an overfull line, because you have 7pt occupied at each side. Using `\centerline` is almost never good.

Comment: @egreg Thanks a lot. Using `\bfseries` instead of `\textbf` is simply to avoid so many curly brackets? I also defined another box that is shorter than this one. How to center it without using `\centerline`? The command is as follows: `\newcommand*{\mysbox}[1]{\centerline{\lfbox[padding = 4pt, padding-left = 10em, padding-right = 10em]{\bfseries\large #1}}}`

Comment: @egreg sorry for asking so many elementary questions. Why did you add two `%` in the command?

Comment: @LinJing In order to avoid spaces creeping in the output. See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116308/discussion-between-lin-jing-and-egreg).

Comment: @egreg When I try to add the Advanced feature 'extra-split={1.5\baselineskip}' (Pg. 16 in the documentation) to a \begin{longfbox} ...\end{longfbox} environment, the error 'Package options Error: option "/fbox/extra-split": unknown option.' appears. What's /fbox got to do with the \begin{longfbox} ...\end{longfbox} environment?

Comment: @RosesBouquet I guess it's better to make a new question with the details.

Comment: @egreg - Thank you for the feedback. Will do ... as soon as I have a moment to assemble a MWE ... The longfbox package is dated 2015-12-05 ... I hope someone is still maintaining the package ;-)