# longfbox and moderncv

Tags: moderncv, undefined

In a `moderncv` document, I get "Undefined control sequence" when I use `longfbox`:

```latex
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage{longfbox}

\name{First}{Last}
\begin{document}
  Lorem
\end{document}
```

The output seems to be generated OK, but LaTeX throws an error about `@makefntext`:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdwtools/footnote.sty:170: Undefined control sequence.
l.170 \expandafter\@tempa\@makefntext
                                     \@@\@@@
```

I already checked [Error with longfbox package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/571207/error-with-longfbox-package) and [Using footnotes with moderncv class in LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779686/using-footnotes-with-moderncv-class-in-latex), but those seems to be different issues.

Comment: it is the same as in your second link: the package expects some setup for footnotes that the class doesn't provide.  Try if it works if you load footmisc.

Comment: You are right. I tried it before, but missed that the order matters of course.

Answer (score 1):

Kudos to [Ulrike-Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/696402/longfbox-and-moderncv#comment1729209_696402):  adding `footmisc` *before* `longfbox` works as mentioned in [Using footnotes with moderncv class in LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779686/using-footnotes-with-moderncv-class-in-latex):

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage{footmisc}  % Insert this usepackage before longfbox
\usepackage{longfbox}

\name{First}{Last}
\begin{document}
  Lorem
\end{document}
```